# How to save User Preferences With Python without using bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()?

Tags: python, customization, operator

The question is very short, so it is simply this:

How can I save user preferences, without using `bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()`?

I'd like to create a function that would save everything or some part of the preferences, without the use of the operator.
I don't know if this is possible.

The main intention is to save only some preferences, for example some custom preferences in a `bpy.types.AddonPreferences` pointer property

Comment: It's not possible to save the preferences as userpref, that is, in the preferences file, without using `save_userpref()` but it is possible to write a utility that saves them to a separate file and then restores them before using them.  If that's a suitable approach I can write up an example.

Comment: I think it would be interesting, if you are sure there is no other way (And I think so too)

Answer (score 4):

Blender does not export a low level interface to the preferences file, nor is the format of the file documented.  The interface is documented under [Preference Operators](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.preferences.html) and the contents, but not layout, of the preferences are documented starting at [`bpy.types.Preferences`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Preferences.html).

However, you can use Blender's *presets* facility to maintain your own settings in files that are stored with your add-on. This mechanism is described in [Using Blender's presets in Python](https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-blenders-presets-in-python/) and you can find a skeleton add-on that demonstrates presets in my [Skeleton github repository](https://github.com/martyfouts/skeleton)

A preset is a Python file containing a collection of settings values.  Here's an example from my skeleton add-on:

```py
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene

scene.name_from = 'Alice'
scene.name_to = 'Bob'
scene.message_text = 'whatcher?'
```

It's just a collection of statements that set the values of properties, in this case three string properties that I've added to `scene` called `name_from`, `name_to`, and `message_text`.

A collection of related presets is stored in a single directory under you addon.  These preferences are used in a panel, so they're store in skeleton/skeleton.panel.

Operator presets are described to blender by deriving a class from `AddPresetBase`:

```py
from bl_operators.presets import AddPresetBase

class MT_MyPresets(Menu): 
    bl_label = 'My Presets' 
    preset_subdir = 'object/my_presets' 
    preset_operator = 'script.execute_preset' 
    draw = Menu.draw_preset

class OT_AddMyPreset(AddPresetBase, Operator):
    bl_idname = 'my.add_preset'
    bl_label = 'Add A preset'
    preset_menu = 'MT_MyPresets'

    # Common variable used for all preset values
    preset_defines = [
                        'obj = bpy.context.object',
                        'scene = bpy.context.scene'
                     ]

    # Properties to store in the preset
    preset_values = [
                        'obj.show_axis',
                        'obj.show_name',
                        'obj.show_bounds',
                        'scene.world'
                    ]

    # Directory to store the presets
    preset_subdir = 'object/my_presets'
```

Blender will handle the I/O between your operator and the presets.

Panel presets are created by deriving a class from `Panel` and `PresetPanel`:

```py
from bl_ui.utils import PresetPanel
from bpy.types import Panel, Menu

# [...]

class MY_PT_presets(PresetPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = 'My Presets'
    preset_subdir = 'object/my_presets'
    preset_operator = 'script.execute_preset'
    preset_add_operator = 'my.add_preset'

# Now we need to make our actual panel draw the header from the presets panel

class My_PT_Panel(Panel):
    bl_label = 'My Panel'
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = 'output'

    def draw_header_preset(self, _context):
        MY_PT_presets.draw_panel_header(self.layout)

    def draw(self, context):    
        # The rest of our panel's code 
        pass
```

You can also use a helper function to copy predefined presets to their starting points, or you can zip your add-on with the predefined presets included.